# Largest number of eɪ sounds in a word

Tags: english, language

This is a simple puzzle about English words.

Which English word has the largest number of eɪ sounds in it? The phonetic sound /eɪ/ is the same as the letter "A" or the "ay" in day or the "eigh" in "eight".

To make it more like a competition, if two people get the same number of /eɪ/  sounds, the winner is the one with largest number of different spellings for the sound in the word. If people tie on that then it is longer word.  If that is equal too it is the first answer.

If there is a dispute about pronunciation and what is a proper word, I will take whatever the OED says as gospel.

---

I have already been made to tighten the rules thanks to a clever answer by  rand al'thor.  No hyphens or spaces are allowed.

**Winning word so far**

- mainstaysails

Comment: Are the words allowed to have any *other* vowel sounds in them (e.g. pot**a**to) or only eɪ?

Comment: @randal'thor Yes. But you may fall foul of one of the tie-breaking rules.

Comment: Great-great-grandmother isn't in the OED? Great-great-grandfather is mentioned as a valid English word in [the online Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/great).

Comment: @randal'thor They are valid words just not according to my definition. I have now just banned hyphens as its much cleaner.  Curiously great-great-grandfather is in the OED.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Three

> mainstaysails

This [is a word](https://www.wordnik.com/words/mainstaysail), and the OP has confirmed that it appears in the OED.

There are many examples with **two**, including:

> waylay, Mayday, eighty-eight, maintain, gateway, mainstay, failsafe, gainsay, staysail, straightaway, railway, staysail, ratepayers, ...

If we were allowed to use hyphens, we could use these to construct words with **four**:

> gateway-maintainers, railway-ratepayers, ...

### Arbitrarily many (now disallowed)

> great-great-great-great-great-great-...-great-great-grandmother

Comment: @Lembik **:->**

Comment: Do you mind if I ban this? I mean it's clever but wasn't quite the point.

Comment: Seriously though, I do think this is a valid answer. As far as I know, there's no maximum $n$ such that ($n$ greats)-grandmother is no longer a valid word.

Comment: I know I know. The point is that I wasn't clever enough to ban it but I would have done had I thought of it.

Comment: @Lembik Can you come up with a reasonable rule under which this would be banned? If so, then sure, I won't mind :-)

Comment: Done. But I have also upvoted your clever answer.

Comment: waylay and Mayday are great. eighty-eight is not a legitimate spelling apparently.

Comment: While technically you can say great-great... any times, after like a few thousands (?) iterations, or so, you will run out of people to point at, as you get closer and closer to Eve (as in Adam and Eve in paradise).

Comment: Neither gateway-maintainers nor railway-ratepayers are in the OED.

Comment: mainstaysail is there :)

Comment: @Lembik Yay! :-D

Comment: Oh I found a longer word... mainstaysails  :)

Comment: @Lembik Heh :-) Edited.

Comment: _Mainstaysail(s)_ is arguably good, but it does require including non-primary pronunciations: the most common pronunciation of _mainstaysail(s)_ (which still isn’t really ‘common’ at all) is /ˈmeɪnsteɪsəl(s)/, with the final diphthong reduced to a schwa, similar to _studdingsail_ /ˈstʌnsəl/ and _topsail_ /ˈtɒpsəl/. I’ve also heard it pronounced /ˈmεnstəl/, but I’m pretty sure that’s a definitely _non_-standard pronunciation.

Answer (score 4):

Heres a few for two:

> Payday, breakaway, cableway, fadeaway, gainsay, graymail, haymaker,  mayonnaise, playdate

## But I think I found the winner:

It is 189'819 letters long, takes 3 hours to pronounce and is the real word for the protein 'titin'. I'm not going to bother counting the 'ay' sounds in it.

It is too long to post here as the limit is 30'000 letters but [here](http://www.digitalspy.com/fun/news/a444700/longest-word-has-189819-letters-takes-three-hours-to-pronounce/) is a link to it.

Comment: I already found a whole bunch for two :-)

Comment: @randal'thor i'm looking for a 3 but can't find one

Comment: I particularly like your ones with different spellings like mayonnaise.

Comment: @Beastly Found one! :-D

Comment: @randal'thor I found a 189'819 letter long word. Think I win :P. Shame it doesn't appear in the OED but it would increase in size 1000 times

Comment: Yes, that's the trouble with questions like this: they can often be 'won' by some massively long-arsed word for some chemical thing that almost nobody's ever heard of.

Comment: Sadly the OED doesn't contain any 189819 long words.  I believe the longest word in there is pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis .

Comment: Yeah @randal'thor wins but that was just a fun idea

Comment: This word consists entirely of the following units: acetyl, alanyl, arginyl, asparaginyl, aspartyl, cysteinyl, ethionyl, glutaminyl, glutamyl, glycyl, histidyl, isoleucyl, leucyl, lysyl, methionyl, phenyl, prolyl, serxisoleucine, seryl, threonyl, titinmethionyl, tryptophyl, tyrosyl and valyl. None of these contains an /eɪ/ sound, so this word actually scores zero :-)

Answer (score 2):

Shortest 2-eɪ words?

> [nene](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nene)
>   
>  neɪ-neɪ
>  
>  [epee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epee)
>   
>  eɪ-peɪ
>    (not primary pronunciation)

Comment: I like nene as an example.

Comment: Scientists are still searching for a 2-eɪ word with only one vowel. For pure per-letter potency, @Lembik, hard to imagine anything more efficient than your original "a."

Comment: "aye aye" is almost a word as in "Aye, aye, what have we here?"

Comment: Aye, indeed, and Finnish does have ["hei hei"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hei_hei)

Answer (score 0):

Hm. So I suppose that

> Eight million eight hundred and eighty-eight thousand, eight hundred and eighty-eight point eight eight (8,888,888.88)

would not be accepted, huh?

Comment: Maybe add billion and trillion to it

Comment: Seems to have spaces.